# Find the earliest date for each product where net income is over $100k

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose that my SQL table has 4 columns: Product, Date, Net_Income, and Cumulative_Net_Income. I want to add a fifth column that shows the first date, for each product, where cumulative net income crosses $100k.

My initial thought is to create a temporary table using

```sql
Select Product,
      min(Date)
From Table
Where Cumulative_Net_Income > '100,000'
Group By Product
```

This can then be joined back to the original table.

However, Is there a simpler or easier approach where I won't have to create separate tables before joining it back?

Comment: `'100,000'` is likely going to cause an error, assuming that `Cumulative_Net_Income` is a numerical data type. Why not `100000`?

Comment: Are you really using SQL Server 2008 as well? 2008 hasn't been supported since 2019.

Comment: As for an "easier" approach, a conditional windowed `MIN` would be easier, and wouldn't need a temporary/derived table.

Comment: The problem is if he wanna set first date for all rows, even those where Accumulated amount is < 100000, then it might be tricky to use window functions. But you don't need an extra table, you just create a subquery and join on it like: update t set minDate = firstDate from table t inner join (select min(date) as firstDate, product from table t2 t2.Cumulative_Net_Income  > 100000 group by product ) t2 ON t2.product = t.product

Comment: @Larnu - sometimes people don't have a choice .... I only just upgraded my production SQL box from 2008 to 2019 towards the end of last year.  Often an upgrade of the SQL version is inhibited by the use of legacy applications that can't support newer versions

Comment: When you say you want to "add a fifth column", do you mean that you're actually going to modify the table structure, or are you just talking about some output that you need for reporting?  To me, it doesn't even necessarily make sense that there is a specific "cumulative" column in your table structure since that's an aggregate value that can be calculated.  I guess it depends on what control you ultimately have over your database structure

Comment: @Craig you'd also be surprised at how many times people aren't aware the version has been entirely unsupported for (well over) 3 years and how many times people mistag. The comment is meant as much as an educational comment as much as a warning that using such an old version is a (significant) vulnerability. We still, at the office, have a 2012 box, which we going to 2022 in the near future. The cause for the delay for the upgrade was both COVID related at our end (postponing 2019) and the late release of 2022 (we decided that the "risk" of using the product for 6~ months was worth the wait).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know it was possible until I tried it, but conditional aggregation can be combined with window functions to get your result.

"Conditional aggregation" is an informal term that refers to putting a `CASE` expression inside an aggregation function (like `MIN()` or `SUM()`) to selectively include or exclude values from consideration. Window functions are aggregate calculations that are calculated over a range of values as defined by the `OVER(...)` clause within the final select.  Putting the two together lets us ask for the minimum date where Cumulative_Net_Income exceeds 100000 within the context of each distinct product.

```
Select *,
    Min(Case When Cumulative_Net_Income > 100000 Then Date End)
        Over(Partition BY PD.Product) AS HundredGrandDate
From ProductData
Order By Product, Date
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JeKqRv8c) which include both the above and the approach your originally proposed using a separate min-date calculation joined with the original data. I don't know if one form has any performance advantage over the other.

Using some arbitrary test data, the following result is produced:

| Product | Date | Net_Income | Cumulative_Net_Income | HundredGrandDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 2023-01-01 | 10000.0000 | 10000.0000 | 2023-01-04 |
| aaa | 2023-01-02 | 30000.0000 | 40000.0000 | 2023-01-04 |
| aaa | 2023-01-03 | 50000.0000 | 90000.0000 | 2023-01-04 |
| aaa | 2023-01-04 | 70000.0000 | 160000.0000 | 2023-01-04 |
| aaa | 2023-01-05 | 90000.0000 | 250000.0000 | 2023-01-04 |
| bbb | 2023-01-01 | 50000.0000 | 50000.0000 | 2023-01-03 |
| bbb | 2023-01-02 | 50000.0000 | 100000.0000 | 2023-01-03 |
| bbb | 2023-01-03 | 50000.0000 | 150000.0000 | 2023-01-03 |
| bbb | 2023-01-04 | 50000.0000 | 200000.0000 | 2023-01-03 |
| ccc | 2023-01-01 | 1000.0000 | 1000.0000 | null |
| ccc | 2023-01-02 | 1000.0000 | 2000.0000 | null |
| ccc | 2023-01-03 | 1000.0000 | 3000.0000 | null |
| ccc | 2023-01-04 | 1000.0000 | 4000.0000 | null |
| ccc | 2023-01-05 | 1000.0000 | 5000.0000 | null |

(In retrospect, I should have called the result column `OverHundredGrandDate` because of the `>` condition.)